# Overload operator<< from function return

Tags: c++

I am trying to develop a simple logger.

I have a function with the following prototype:

```
class Logger{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<MyStream> & getLogger(string, string);
}
```

and i want to do something like

```
logger = Logger();
logger.log("INF", "HGH") << "My message" << endl;
```

for this i overloaded the operator<<

```
template<typename T>
inline friend std::unique_ptr<MyStream> &operator<<(std::unique_ptr<MyStream>&os, const T&val){
    *os << val;
    return os;
}
inline friend std::unique_ptr<MyStream>& operator<<(std::unique_ptr<MyStream>&os, std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&) ){
    *os << f;
    return os;
}
```

But when i try to do

```
auto infLogger = log.log(M_LOG_NRM, M_LOG_INF);
infLogger<< "Testing new functionality" << std::endl;
```

Everything works fine but when i do:

```
log.log("MOD1", M_LOG_NRM, M_LOG_INF) << "Testing new functionality" << std::endl;
```

I have this nice compilation error:

```
cannot convert ‘jpCppLibs::Logger::log(int, int)(std::basic_string<char>(((const char*)"MOD1"), (*(const std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>()))), 3, 3)’ (type ‘std::unique_ptr<jpCppLibs::MyStream>’) to type ‘std::unique_ptr<jpCppLibs::MyStream>&’
   log.log(M_LOG_NRM, M_LOG_INF) << "Testing new functionality" << std::endl;
```

Any help?

The class was working passing by parameter the message and the format+variables, just trying to improve it a little bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
inline friend std::unique_ptr<MyStream> const&operator<<(std::unique_ptr<MyStream> const&os, const T&val){
  *os << val;
  return os;
}
```

note that a `std::unique_ptr<MyStream> const&` and `std::unique_ptr<MyStream const>&` are different types.  The first is a reference to a immutable smart pointer to mutable data, the second is a reference to a mutable smart pointer to immutable data.

Temporary objects cannot bind to non-`const` lvalue references, as protection against implicit conversions leading to changes being discarded silently.  However, you do not need a non-`const` lvalue reference, so there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to initialize a non-const reference with
a temporary, and that's not allowed.

The usual solution for this problem is to write a small class
(which may contain nothing more than your `std::unique_ptr`),
with a template member `operator<<`; the rules allow member
functions to be called on temporaries.